# How to get the relative file path in PHP

Tags: php

**The structure**

```
libs/functions.php
test/b.php
a.php
content.html
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php
function showContent() {
    return file_get_contents('content.html');
}
```

**a.php**

```
<?php
include 'libs/functions.php';
echo showContent();
```

**b.php**

```
<?php
include '../libs/functions.php';
echo showContent();
```

**content.html**

```
test
```

a.php will show the word *test*, but b.php is in the test folder, therefore the file path will be wrong, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

please use the following:

```
$basePath = dirname(__FILE__);
```

use this `$basePath` prefixing to any include or require statement.

I hope this would help

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking about this from the wrong direction.

Instead, of opening the different php files, create one file `index.php` that `includes` and works with the scripts you need. That way you will always be at the root and will be able to access the files/functions you need.

Another way is *cloning* the directory in sub-directories, but I **do NOT** suggest that option. You will just get confused over time.

Comment: Actually I am writing smarty plugin, and hope php file in backend can do the same thing just as front end, I use phpThumb class for creating thumbnail image, it need do do something like `<img src="libs/phpthumb.php?src=../uploads/test.jpg">`, that why I need to give the correct path for the class

Comment: And I don't want to ask question too complicated, so I just mention the function I need

Comment: Why can't you use something like `src="/?method=img&src=uploads/test.jpg"` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use document root as start of your path so you never have to worry about it.

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/libs/functions.php'
```

and

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/content.html'
```

Comment: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] will always point to document root for the host. so you will have to take care of this if the project is in subfolders and will have to create virtual host for the same.

Comment: DOCUMENT_ROO in windows will make the path like `C:\wamp\www\...`, I need to get the relative path, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need to do this but one solution would be to create an index with the all php files from the folders you want.

Another solution may be to set a **constant** path from the **base path**. You can get the root of the website using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. This is the fastest solution and by setting this constant you will always refer directly functions.php file.